# unable to use Pandas concat method method with a list object

Tags: pandas

I am using `Jupyter`. I have two objects of type `verticapy.vdataframe.vDataFrame` - `train_vdf` and `test_vdf`.

I combine them into a list (or at least it looks like that is what is happening) like this

```
combine = [train_vdf, test_vdf] #gives a list
```

`type(combine)` shows result `list`.

When I try to use `combine` to create a `pandas` `dataframe`, I get error that `combine` is of type `vDataFrame`

```
combine_pdf = pd.concat(combine)
```

`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'verticapy.vdataframe.vDataFrame'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Is `combine` list or `vDataFrame`?

Comment: `combine` is a `list`, but its elements are `vDataFrame`. `concat` requires the elements to be `Series` or `DataFrame`.

Comment: happy to accept your answer if you can provide one.

Comment: I never used `verticapy` so I can't really provide you with a workaround :/

Comment: you already have my friend. I had to convert `vDataFrame` into a `panda` `dataframe` using `vDataFrame`'s `to_panda` function. `combine = [train_vdf.to_pandas(), test_vdf.to_pandas()]`